# How to pass created post to its own view in Flask?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is the code. I have a model where there is a class Item.

```
class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __init__(self,title,content,category):
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.category = category

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Item %r>' % self.title

@app.route('/create',methods=('GET','POST'))
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('title') and request.form.get('content'):
            item = Item(request.form['title'],request.form['content'],request.form['category'])
            flash('Item created successfully','success')
            db.session.add(item)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('view'),item=item)
        else:
            flash('Title and Content are required.','danger')
    form = ItemForm()
    return render_template('create.html',form=form)
@app.route('/view/<item>')
def view(item):
    query = Item.query.filter_by(title=item.title)
    return render_template('view.html',item=item)
```

As you can see, I create the item in the create route based on the Item class. Then I pass it with item=item as a parameter in the redirect to the view. But right now the view doesn't like my item. I get the error:

```
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'view'. Did you forget to specify values ['item']?
```

I think I'm somehow supposed to pass the item pieces independently? like the title and content and category as needed? I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `item` parameter in your `url_for` function instead of the `render_template` function:

```
def create():
    # ...
    return redirect(url_for('view', item=item))
```

**NOTE**

Also it is not related to your error directly: You need to take care to pass the **`Item` object** to your `render_template()` function in your `view` endpoint. At the moment you are just passing the **item title**. This is a contradiction to how you handle it in the `create` endpoint where you pass the whole object. I assume you want to use all properties of the item object and not just the title.

As an addition it is much better to use the primary key (`id`) as identifier as the title as your item title might change over time or there may be dupes, but the id will stay unique. My proposed change:

```
@app.route('/view/<itemid>')
def view(itemid):
    item = Item.query.filter(itemid).first_or_404()
    return render_template('view.html', item=item)
```

Comment: can you post the entire create function code you are thinking of? I am not sure if you mean that this redirect should go in the if request.method == 'POST' logic? (it already is), or outside just as the function return. This is also confusing as it would be the same return no matter if the request was a post or a get right? And where would I get the item in this case? currently, in the outer loop, all I have is the form object

Comment: never mind, I get it. I missed that the parameter is passed in url_for, not the redirect part. I think you made a typo when you said instead of the render_template function?